# How to exclude a recently added user from a list of users in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have API endpoint /department/getManagersList?department_name=IT which is returning this

```
{
"status": "success",
"managersList": [
    {
        "id": "6103d29974535fac35286aff",
        "name": "axe deo",
        "role": "Associate React Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": "6103d1e274535fac35286afe",
        "name": "aakash kumar",
        "role": "Vice President Engineering"
    },
    {
        "id": "6103d36074535fac35286b0a",
        "name": "atanu paul",
        "role": "Senior Software Enginner"
    },
    {
        "id": "6103d7c1f2bba5af7cad4083",
        "name": "sam winchester",
        "role": "Junior Node JS Developer"
    }
]
  }
```

now "sam Winchester" is a new user who just created his profile I want to exclude him or in a nutshell, remove the newly created user from this list. The purpose is to return the names of all the employees of the department excluding the newly created user so that the new user can choose his/her reporting manager. Any idea how to do this?
This is the current code that is returning the above JSON object

```
adminController.getManagersList = async (req, res) => {
try {
var manager_list = []; 
var department_data = {}; 
var employees_list = []; 
var manager_details = {};
var department_name = req.query.department_name;

if (isEmpty(department_name))
  return res.status(400).json({
    status: "failure",
    message: `Department name ${emptyField}`,
  });
department_data = await DepartmentData.findOne({
  department_name: department_name,
})
  .populate("employees")
  .exec();
if (isEmpty(department_data))
  return res
    .status(400)
    .json({ status: "failure", message: `Department ${dataNotFound}` });

employees_list = department_data.employees;

employees_list.forEach((empList) => {
  let department_data = empList.department;
  department_data.forEach((depList) => {
    if (depList.name == department_name) {
      manager_details = {}; // * Making the object empty for next value
      manager_details.id = empList._id;
      manager_details.name = empList.full_name;
      manager_details.role = depList.role;
      manager_list.push(manager_details);
    }
  });
  
});
res.status(200).json({ status: "success", managersList: manager_list });
} catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
   res
    .status(500)
    .json({ status: "failure", message: "Internal Server Error" });
 }
 };
```

Comment: If you have access to the new user's id you could filter that user out. Use → 
`response.managersList = response.managersList.filter(({ id }) => id !== <emp-id>)`

Comment: yes i do have access to new user id, ket me give that a try

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last item from your array you could use:

```
const arr = [1,2,3];
arr.pop();
// arr -> [1,2]
```

Comment: Or `arr.slice(0, -1)` to avoid unnecessary mutation of the source array.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you already answered your question here:

> The purpose is to return the names of all the employees of the department excluding the newly created user so that the new user can choose his/her reporting manager.

So that you need find all employees who do not have managers yet.
I assume that you have relationship between managers and users as `one-to-many`, (one manager can have many employees). Not sure what database are you using, but should be something like this:

```
department_data = await DepartmentData.findOne({
    department_name: department_name,
})
.populate({
    path: 'employees',
    match: { managerId: { $eq: null }},
})
.exec();
```

also rename "getManagersList" to "getEmployeesList"

Comment: there is no separate DB fro manager, it's coming from the same database as employee

Comment: ) sure, I mean not sure which kind of database (mySql, Postgres, MongoDB... etc) is used. Have you tried example above, if yes, what result you get?

Comment: the database is MongoDB, I have used the splice method example above, seems to work so far.